# Finding a maximum on a plot

Tags: maximum

My script is currently:

```
 NDSolve[{cd'[t] == -k1 cd[t], cd[0] == c0, 
     cno'[t] == k1 cd[t] eNO - k2 o cno[t]^2, cno[0] == 0}, {cd, 
     cno}, {t, 0, 2400}]

Plot[Evaluate[cno[t] /. %], {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 10 10^-6}]
```

this gives me my plot and what I want to get the actual value for the max of this curve?

I am not sure what code to put in after `FindMaximum` to get it.

Comment: Please add some more details to your code so that there is a minimum working example - right now if I paste the code you shared into Mathematica I just get a load of errors because a lot of things are undefined :) You may have success trying `FindMaximum[Evaluate[cno[t] /. %], {t, 1}]`, or consider looking at `NMaximize`.

Answer (score 2):

You could include a [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent) in your ODE to capture local maxima. First, some random values for your constants:

```
k1 = .3;
k2 = .7;
o = 10;
c0 = 1;
eNO = 5;
```

Then, use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) with [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent):

```
{sol, {max}} = Reap @ NDSolveValue[
    {
    cd'[t] == -k1 cd[t], cd[0] == c0, cno'[t] == k1 cd[t] eNO - k2 o cno[t]^2, cno[0]==0,
    WhenEvent[cno'[t] == 0, Sow @ cno[t]]
    },
    {cd, cno},
    {t, 0, 2400}
];
```

There is only 1 maximum:

```
max
```

> {0.415782}

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol[[2]][t], {t, 0, 10}, GridLines -> {None, max}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
eqns = {cd'[t] == -k1 cd[t], cd[0] == c0, 
   cno'[t] == k1 cd[t] eNO - k2 o cno[t]^2, cno[0] == 0};
```

The equations can be solved using [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
sol = DSolve[eqns, {cd, cno}, t][[1]] // Quiet

(* {cd -> Function[{t}, c0 E^(-k1 t)], 
 cno -> Function[{t}, (-Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[E^(-k1 t)] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k1]
        BesselI[1, (2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[E^(-k1 t)] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/
        Sqrt[k1]] BesselK[1, (2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/Sqrt[
        k1]] + Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[E^(-k1 t)] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k1]
        BesselI[1, (2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/Sqrt[k1]] BesselK[
        1, (2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[E^(-k1 t)] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/Sqrt[
        k1]])/(Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[
      o] (BesselI[1, (2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/Sqrt[
          k1]] BesselK[0, (
          2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[E^(-k1 t)] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/Sqrt[k1]] + 
        BesselI[0, (2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[E^(-k1 t)] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/
          Sqrt[k1]] BesselK[1, (2 Sqrt[c0] Sqrt[eNO] Sqrt[k2] Sqrt[o])/Sqrt[
          k1]]))]} *)
```

Verifying that `sol` satisfies the equations

```
eqns /. sol // FullSimplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Using the constants used by Carl Woll

```
k1 = 3/10;
k2 = 7/10;
o = 10;
c0 = 1;
eNO = 5;

NMaximize[cno[t] /. sol, t]

(* {0.415782, {t -> 0.715805}} *)
```

Or

```
FindMaximum[cno[t] /. sol, t]

(* {0.415782, {t -> 0.715805}} *)
```